# replace comboBox value into number when inserted into sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, combobox

I know how to insert the comboBox value into sql but no idea on how to replace the comboBox value with number in sql.

This is some part of my comboBox coding and process button.

**User.java**

```
 JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
           comboBox_1.setBounds(126, 105, 140, 20);
           contentPane.add(comboBox_1);
           comboBox_1.addItem("RM100-RM200");
           comboBox_1.addItem("RM200-RM300");
           comboBox_1.addItem("RM300-RM400");

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Process");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(360, 296, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String a=(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
         Case ca= new Case();
      try {
                    ca.addPlace(a);
                    LoginGUI um= new LoginGUI();
                    um.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        });
```

**Case.java**

```
        public void addPlace( String r) throws Exception{

        DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connect=db.getConnection();
        String sql="Insert into menu(Budget)VALUES (?)";

        PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,r);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        connect.close();
        ps.close();

    }
```

Let say the user select RM100-RM200, value "1" will be inserted into sql instead of RM100-RM200. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java comboboxes contain a `getSelectedIndex` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex--

Comment: can i change the number by myself?

Comment: Yes, using setSelectedItem or setSelectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested you code?
In your actionPerformed() you have written,

> String a = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

The object comboBox is nowhere initialised in the code.
Do you mean comboBox_1 because it is  the only object of JcomboBox which you have actually initialised in code.

Also

> (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

The typecast to String is actually not needed as toString return a String only.

Comment: sorry my bad..it should be  String a=(String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();